# Android how to determine user kills the app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle

After review many questions on satck overflow I know that onDestroy() only called when system kills the app and the function of isFinishing(). But is there any function like onDestroy() that let me know user kills the app(swipe). I tried onStop() and onPause(), they don't work either. Thank you.

Comment: Could you do whatever you're doing when the app next runs? If the system killed the process, when the `Activity` is next created you'll get a `savedInstanceState` `Bundle` passed into `onCreate`. If the user closed the app instead, `savedInstanceState` will be *null* - so you can check that and do things like clean up saved state, etc.

Answer (score 0):

onDestroy is called when an activity is removed from the task stack, but something else is keeping the process running. This is usaully when the user hits the back button or if the configuration changes and it needs to be rebuilt.

If the activity is removed from the task stack, and that was the only thing keeping the process alive, then the entire process will usually simply be killed, in which case onDestroy is not called.

Note that if the user simply switches to another app, then the process will also simply be killed, without onDestroy being called.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#ondestroy

I find it helpful to simply pretend as if the onDestroy method does not exist.

Comment: `onDestroy` is vital for cleaning up resources and listeners that should not outlive the activity. It’s just no good as a hook for saving anything.